# Freshly installed Apache - IndexOptions not working

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I recently installed a XAMPP 1.8.3.3 to RedHat. I just simply created a link to the `htdocs` folder, plan to use the directory listing feature.
I would like to see the whole length of my directory names.

I made the following changes to `lampp/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +NameWidth=*
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After restarting the service, nothing happens, my directory structure is still the same, names shortened and stuff. Any Idea what is causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved my own problem, working like a charm.

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory ~ "/.*/">
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +NameWidth=*
</Directory>
```